# PHP and Apache2, anything else required for a socket server?

Tags: php, html, apache2, websocket

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, Apache2, PHP5.3 and Chromium 14. Should I be able to use HTML5 WebSockets straight away or do I need something else to get up and running?

(I'm 100% new to sockets and am having considerable difficulty)

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262543/what-are-good-resources-for-learning-html-5-websockets

Answer (score 0):

Apache is HTTP server, and HTTP is a protocol that's different to WebSocket protocol.
Therefore Apache doesn't serve stuff requested via WebSockekts protocol.

In other words, Apache has nothing to do with WebSockets and therefore doesn't serve any content if requested via WS protocol.

What you need is a WebSocket server. Googling for "WebSocket server" should give enough results for you to choose desired WS server.

Comment: Ok so if Apache isn't anything to do with it, can I connect directly to PHP using its native socket functions?

Comment: You can create a WS server in PHP, however you need to have it listen on a different port to port 80.